# Adding To Association Table Without Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables: `A`, `B`, and an association table `AB`. Since Entity Framework does not create a separate entity for the association table, only entities `A` and `B` are created.

Now, I want to add `B`s to the `A` entity but I do not want to load all these `B` entities from the database since I know the Id's of the `B` entities I want to add to `A`. I tried to do the following:

```
A.Bs.Add(
    new B(){
        Id = 100
    }
);
```

The problem is that when there is no `B` entity with `Id` of `100`, instead of throwing an exception due to the foreign key constraint, EF creates a new `B` entity with `Id` of `100` and then adds this to the association table.

How can I prevent the creation of a new `B`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like creating the B object outside the Add operation and either attaching it to the context or marking its state as "Unchanged" works as required.

```
var b = new B(){
    Id = 100
};

context.B.Attach(b);
//OR
context.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

A.Bs.Add(b);
```